# Strange behavior of mathtools with showonlyrefs

Tags: mathtools

With the following code :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
A & = B  \label{eq:first}\\
  & = C \tag{a} 
\end{align}

Reference to \eqref{eq:first}.

\end{document}
```

I obtain the following result:

[image]

With `\tag*` instead of `\tag`, I have the expected result.

Of course, it doesn't seem logical to put `\tag{a}` without the option `showmanualtags` but the result seems strange.

Comment: It might be a nice puzzle to solve but: (1) I can't see a reason for mixing numbers and manual tags in the same display; (2) I can't see a reason for not showing manual tags unless referred to; (3) I can't see a reason for `showonlyrefs`. Reasons are in order of importance.